# Get input values in a form, relative to a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have forms similar to this:

```
<form class="submission-form" method="POST" action="/post/create/">
  <input type="text" name="title">
  <textarea name="post_content"></textarea>
  <select name="visibility" class="form-control">
    <option value="1">Public</option>
    <option value="2">Private</option>
  </select>
  <input class="submit-button" type="button" value="Publish">
</form>
```

The various fields in the form are not known beforehand and can change; what is known is the fact that every form that needs processing has a `submission-form` class on it, and it contains a button with the class `submit-button`.

I'm trying to add an event listener on the `input.submit-button` that will traverse on the form its contained in, find all the fields, and create an object from it. For example, in the above case, the object created might look like:

```
{
  title: "My first post",
  post_content: "Hello there!",
  visibility: 1
}
```

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: try this https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Comment: @PrasunJajodia That returns an array, not an object.

Comment: Do you really need an object? Or is anything that can be used as the `data:` option to `$.ajax()` OK?

Comment: `$(this).closest(".submission-form").serialize()` will return a URL-encoded string.

Comment: Someone created a plugin that handles some of the edge cases better than the solutions listed here: https://github.com/macek/jquery-serialize-object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through input, textarea and select elements and create an object with properties from element name and value:

```js
$('.submit-button').on('click', function() {
  var o = {};
  $(this).closest('form')
    .find('input, textarea, select')
    .not(':button')
    .each(function() {
      o[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val()
    });
  console.log(o);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="submission-form" method="POST" action="/post/create/">
  <input type="text" name="title" />
  <textarea name="post_content"></textarea>
  <select name="visibility" class="form-control">
    <option value="1">Public</option>
    <option value="2">Private</option>
  </select>
  <input class="submit-button" type="button" value="Publish" />
</form>
```

**References**

[.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

[.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

[.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Comment: `.closest()` is better than `.parents()`. It stops as soon as it finds the first match, instead of searching the entire DOM hierarchy.

Comment: @Barmar In DOM structure like this one doesn't really matter. In any case closest is faster so I replaced it :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `serializeArray()` and then use `reduce()` on that array to return desired object.

```js
$("form").submit(function(event) {
  var data = $(this).serializeArray().reduce(function(r, e) {
    r[e.name] = e.value;
    return r;
  }, {})
  console.log(data)
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="submission-form">
  <input type="text" name="title">
  <textarea name="post_content"></textarea>
  <select name="visibility" class="form-control">
    <option value="1">Public</option>
    <option value="2">Private</option>
  </select>
  <input class="submit-button" type="submit" value="Publish">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `serializeArray()` to create and array of objects for name value pairs and loop through them to create a single object.

```js
$('form').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var obj = $(this).serializeArray()
  
  var final= {};
  $.each(obj, function(index,object){
    
      final[object.name] = object.value;
    
  });
  console.log(final);
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="submission-form" method="POST" action="/post/create/">
  <input type="text" name="title">
  <textarea name="post_content"></textarea>
  <select name="visibility" class="form-control">
    <option value="1">Public</option>
    <option value="2">Private</option>
  </select>
  <input class="submit-button" type="submit" value="Publish">
</form>
```